# AJAX GET JSON seems to returns nothing

Tags: javascript, php, android, ajax, json

I am creating an Android application using Intel XDK and for some reason It seems to work on the emulator but on the mobile it seems to fail. Below are the screenshots of what it looks like on the emulator and on the device.

[image: On Emulator, as you can see it says Hello Script47, it has got the session data from my server.]

[image: This is the image on the testing device, as you can see it shows nothing, it should say Hello "Session Name Here"]

Both are using the exact same code and are pointed to the correct database and server. Below is the code I'm using, the PHP and JavaScript code.

```
function getSessionData(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://sm.script47.net/api/v1/modules/sessionData/sessionData.php',
        "type": "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(error);
        },
    });
}
```

Then in another file called home.js.

```
window.onload = function () {
    getSessionData(function (data) {
        window.token = data.token;
        window.userID = data.userID;
        window.username = data.username;
        window.emailAddress = data.emailAddress;

        alert(window.userID);

        getElement("userDetails").innerHTML = "Hello <strong> " + window.username + "</strong>"
    });
};
```

Then to get the session data I'm using the below on a PHP server hosted by namecheap (shared hosting).

```
<?php
session_start();

// I added the code below in the comment block to try and make it work.
/******************************************************/
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
/******************************************************/

$sessionData = array(
    "token" => htmlspecialchars(trim($_SESSION['token'])),
    "userID" => htmlspecialchars(trim($_SESSION['userID'])),
    "username" => htmlspecialchars(trim($_SESSION['username'])),
    "emailAddress" => htmlspecialchars(trim($_SESSION['emailAddress']))
);
echo json_encode($sessionData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I don't know why it won't work or what is causing it to not work which is why I'm not sure what the fix is. I've talked to the namecheap customer support and they said AJAX requests should work, and they do as I use them to login/register but getting the JSON session data on an actual mobile device doesn't seem to work. Also the success/error callback doesn't return anything either.